Dataset for multi-scale control with high leave discrete and low level continuous controls
I need a dataset of controls at a discrete higher scale and continuous lower one. An example would be robotics or autonomy where higher level decisions are things like stop or turn. But I want other examples. Do you know of such a dataset ? For example flow problems where the decision to rout  the flow is discrete and then the flow has continuous control variables and the resulting flow then triggers discrete decision. If not a nice multi scale in robotics would do as well as long as it is explicit in scales.
